# Summing scores from multiple SQLite tables

Tags: sqlite

I have 4 tables as follows:

board1

```
    round    Nspair   Ewpair   NsPoints    EwPpoints
    1        1        1        4           0
    2        4        3        2           2
    3        3        4        0           4
```

board2

```
    round    Nspair   Ewpair   NsPoints        EwPpoints
    1        2        2        2               2
    2        1        4        2               2
    3        4        1        2               2
```

board3

```
    round    Nspair   Ewpair   NsPoints        EwPpoints
    1        3        3        3               1
    2        2        1        3               1
    3        1        2        0               4
```

board4

```
    round    Nspair   Ewpair   NsPoints        EwPpoints
    1        4        4        0               4
    2        3        2        3               1
    3        2        3        3               1
```

I would like to create an SQL query to add up each pairs points something like:

SELECT sum NSpoints from Board1, Board2, Board3, Board4 WHERE Nspair = 1

I tried various ways to achieve this but all seem to fall over when the Nspair does not exist as in board 4 above. This looks like it would be a relatively common task and thus there must be a right way to do it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want a sum of all four, you either need to union them together first, or compute four sums and add those together.  What does "fall over" mean?  Are you getting an error message?  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most correct way to handle this would be a single `board` table with a `board_number` column.

Anyway, create a view that can be handled like a table:

```
CREATE VIEW all_boards AS
SELECT * FROM board1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM board2 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM board3 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM board4;
...
SELECT SUM(NsPoints) FROM all_boards WHERE Nspair = 1;
```

Alternatively, combine the tables dynamically:

```
SELECT SUM(NsPoints)
FROM (SELECT NsPoints, Nspair FROM board1 UNION ALL
      SELECT NsPoints, Nspair FROM board2 UNION ALL
      SELECT NsPoints, Nspair FROM board3 UNION ALL
      SELECT NsPoints, Nspair FROM board4)
WHERE Nspair = 1
```